# Mustache + Sling + CQ5

Tags: java, mustache, aem, sling, templating-engine

I'm researching a means of using Mustache templating for the view engine in CQ5, which uses Sling. I'm looking for some advise if anyone has already had experience going into this.

I need to use a template format that can be shared between front and back end when required. So mustache is ideal, however, other options may be applicable, such as handlebars.

I have found a git repo for "sling-scripting-mustache" which I am looking into but it lacks any kind of documentation. I will be giving it a try nonetheless.

Would appreciate any thoughts and guidance :)

Comment: offtopic, but make sure mustache is your best bet, people often realize they need something that allows for a little more logic, in this case handlebars is a great option.

Comment: Agreed, I would love to start down that path with handlebars. My problem might come later tho as I will have to find similar solutions for .Net, php, and other environments. Mustache seems to have solutions for those, but I haven't found the same solutions for handlebars.

Comment: well handlebars should be languge agnostic as it is run on the client not the server.

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars has been in CQ since 5.6:

> The handlebars javascript library was originally added to CQ in 5.6.0 for other purposes. The java version of handlebars is included in AEM 6.0, and in a featurepack for 5.6.1 that contains the Social Component Framework (SCF)
>   ([source](http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2014-05-22/sightly-vs-handlebars-vs-jsp-comparing-scripting-languages/#comment-1403136239))

You can write Mustache templates and render them with Handlebars:

> Mustache templates are compatible with Handlebars, so you can take a Mustache template, import it into Handlebars, and start taking advantage of the extra Handlebars features
>   ([source](http://handlebarsjs.com))

There's some more info [here](http://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/social-communities/scf.html).

Answer (score 0):

my workflow is usually to compile handlebars or mustache outside of the language pipeline with something like grunt and then include it as a seperate js file.

Now if you are actually trying to do server side templating thats a different issue. Not sure how well handlebars works as a server side template but mustache does for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the repo (https://github.com/lykorian/sling-scripting-mustache) builds a OSGI bundle with the scripting engine information embedded in its metadata.

Based on what I can see in the pom file, you should install the dependencies:

```
mvn -Pinstall-dependencies install
```

And then build and install the actual bundle by installing it in the OSGI console or running maven (check the pom for the default values):

```
mvn -Plocal-author install
```

Once that is installed, the scripting engine should be installed and it should recognize *. mustache files.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, these are just my thoughts based on what is in the code and in the pom file. Hope it helps!

Comment: It must be a private or removed repository, because I get 404.